# Sort A Report by a Summed Amount

Tags: sorting, report, subtotal

MS Office 365.  I have a report sourced by a Query that is grouped, sorted, and subtotaled by Vendor.  Is there a way to sort the report by subtotal (=Sum([Amount]))?  My goal is to have the subtotals in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Click the arrow  Filter drop-down arrow on Row Labels, and pick Sort by Value.[image]

If you click the Column Labels arrow, pick the field you want to sort first, followed by the sort option you want.

In the Sort by Value box, under Select value, pick the value to sort by.
[image]